# How to load python pickle from Julia?

Tags: python, julia, pickle

How can I load a python .pkl (pickle) file from Julia?

Comment: Given that there are over 200 existing questions on Stackoverflow about python pickling, I think this is on-topic.

Comment: I don't you understand what I've written. **seeking recommendations for packages** is not! https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: and now you need to give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you have tried and the errors you're facing

Answer (score 8):

Here is a snippet to load in pickle files directly with PyCall:

```
using PyCall

py"""
import pickle
 
def load_pickle(fpath):
    with open(fpath, "rb") as f:
        data = pickle.load(f)
    return data
"""

load_pickle = py"load_pickle"
```

Then use `load_pickle("<path to file>.pkl")` and it should load it into a Julia `Dict`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use [`Pandas.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaPy/Pandas.jl) to read the `.pkl` file:

```
julia> using Pandas

julia> df = read_pickle("<FILE_NAME>.pkl");
```

Also, You can convert it to a `DataFrames.DataFrame` object in this way:

```
julia> using DataFrames
julia> df1 = DataFrames.DataFrame(df);
```

Then if you check for the type of each object:

```
julia> typeof(df)
Pandas.DataFrame

julia> typeof(df1)
DataFrames.DataFrame
```