# Fastest way to read csv or pickle data for Julia 1.9+

Tags: csv, io, julia, pickle

I have a folder with pickle files that I want to read efficiently from Julia.

So far, I have tried using `Pickle` and `Pandas`, with the latter being faster. Each file is around **120MB, and it takes around 24 seconds per file**, which is a lot considering that in python I can read them almost instantaneously.

Here's a sample of my code.

```
# using Pickle
using Pandas

fn ="./data/second_example.pickle"
@time data = read_pickle(fn);
```

where I'm getting

```
 24.931893 seconds (183.03 M allocations: 5.015 GiB, 16.08% gc time)
```

My question: is there a faster way to read pickle (or csv) files? I could convert them to CSVs and read them as so if there's a fast method for that. I'm using Julia 1.9.1.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: what's in those files, in terms of data types and matrix shapes?

Comment: I would try loading via PyCall or PythonCall e.g. as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65720584/how-to-load-python-pickle-from-julia   Pickle is a Python's format which is not designed for cross-language transfer of data. Use BSON or CSV or Apache Arrow. Those formats will have big throughput. On my machine CSV.jl parsese a 120MB file having 2M rows in one second.

Comment: As others have said, Pickle is a format that store - serialize - python objects, the comparison with Julia packages is a bit unfair. If your data is tabular, CSV will be much faster (and portable)

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz each file is a tuple with the first element being a numpy matrix and the second being a list of tuples.

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel agreed it's an unfair comparison by the data format design, but I thought the difference was enormous. Tried CSV.jl and PyCall.jl but in the end the winner solution was to transform the pickle data into an .npy matrix and read them using NPZ.jl. 

Thanks a ton to everyone

Comment: CC @Antonello .

Comment: @BlasKolic I do not know whether you did any benchmark but perhaps the fastest would have been PyArrow +  Arrow.jl